# How to get access to the native IDataObject

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, com, c++-cli

I'm trying to convert [System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idataobject.aspx) into the native [IDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) defined in the ObjIdl.h. Unfortunately the following source code doesn't return the native IDataObject.

```
IntPtr pData = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetIUnknownForObject(e->Data);
::IDataObject* data = (::IDataObject*) pData.ToPointer();
```

How can I get the native IDataObject in a Windows Forms application during Drag and Drop?

Comment: are you sure you need it? why can't you use the managed IDataObject? although you _could_ do it by pinning the object in the memory and reinterpret_casting, I doubt you should.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I need it, because I use the Windows Forms application only for testing purposes. In the real project I will not include managed code. Can you provide an example for the pinning?

Comment: well, there are two possibilities. if both native and managed implementations happen to share the same memory layout, you can just cast (but don't forget the pinning, otherwise your object may be relocated by .NET framework any time!); otherwise, you'll need to implement a native [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) is an example of pinning in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting a COM interface pointer with a C-style cast is not legal.  You have to ask nicely with the QueryInterface() method.  Like this:

```
 System::Windows::Forms::IDataObject^ obj = Clipboard::GetDataObject();
 ::IUnknown* punk = (::IUnknown*)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetIUnknownForObject(obj).ToPointer();
 ::IDataObject* pdata = nullptr;
 HRESULT hr = punk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(::IDataObject), (void**)&pdata);
 if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
     // etc..
 }
```